# Ошибки в ie11: отсутствует свойство или метод css

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Есть очень большой проект на angular.js используется много сторонних библиотек. Все работает. Только у некоторых клиентов в Windows 7 и IE11.0 сыпится апликация. У себя пытались это репродуцировать, к сожалению, без результатно. 
Есть у кого-нибудь идеи по этому поводу? Если нужна дополнительная информация с радостью предоставлю. Спасибо.
Сыпется в таких местах:

```
var backdropElement = angular.element('<div class="alert-backdrop"/>');
backdropElement.css({
  position: 'fixed',
  top: '0px',
  left: '0px',
  bottom: '0px',
  right: '0px'
});
```

error: Das Objekt unterstützt die Eigenschaft oder Methode "css" nicht

Comment: Возможно у ваших клиентов включен режим эмуляции IE ниже 11 версии, попробуйте, возможно это вам поможет.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin, Спасибо за совет, попробую репродуцировать в режиме эмуляции

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно подключать к сайту [Polyfill](https://philipwalton.github.io/polyfill/)

Comment: А то что у меня в IE11 ошибок нет, это роли не играет? Polyfill.js все равно может помочь?

Comment: Polyfill решает такие проблемы. Bы никогда не знаете, какие клиенты у вас будут. Если конечно вам нужны клиенты c IE